# How to show username after login without database

Tags: android

I have used toast and textview but my app crashes everytime. Kindly see my code and help me. Thanks.

Activity where I want to display:

```
public class Sites extends ListActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sites);

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logged_name);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name1 = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    txt.setText(name1);
}
}
```

Activity from where I have passed username:

```
public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
}
public void login_inside(View view) {
    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_txt);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_txt);

    if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(SignIn.this,
                Sites.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("name",username.getText().toString());
        startActivity(myIntent);
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: can you post complete crash log ?

Comment: store the data using `shared Preference`

Comment: Your question title is not related with the description

Comment: Add crash log here, everything looks cool here

Comment: you mentioned you used toast. where is the toast code?

Comment: alse check this line String name1 = intent.getStringExtra("name");
what is returned by getStringExtra() method you need to debug that also.

Comment: http://prnt.sc/dw7h02
here is screen shot my app stops working

Comment: <activity android:name=".Sites">
        </activity>
here activity in manifest

Comment: Abdul Waheed I removed toast code because it was not working

Comment: @SyedHunain please select AndroidMonitor option as can be seen in attached image by you. By this crash log will be available

Comment: http://prnt.sc/dw7l7k
See here

Comment: @SyedHunain, add full error log, the image is on half

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending `ListActivity` will cause `java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`

So, Change this:

```
public class Sites extends ListActivity {.....
```

With this:

```
public class Sites extends AppCompatActivity {............
```

Comment: Superb it Worked for me. :)

Comment: Can you also tell me how can increase message like right now only user name is coming with this 
String name1 = intent.getStringExtra("name");
But I need it to be centred and add more like Welcome Admin!

Comment: 1st To make textview center, in xml make the gravity center of texxtview. 2nd you can add extra string in your settext like `txt.setText("Hello, Welcome"+name1);`

Comment: is there any way I make first alphabet of username capital as some users have typed there username in small letters first alphabet only ?

Comment: Use `txt.setText("Hello, Welcome"+name1.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+name1.substring(1)) ;`

Comment: One more thing how I can set this up for every screen to show username on every other activity ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the the data in next activity using bundle inside onCreate

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logged_name);
 String value;
 if(extras != null){ // check if there is no data 
 value = extras.getString("name");
 txt.setText(value);
 } else{ "handle the null case" }
```

Comment: this is not the right way. In case extras is null then still you are setting to textview value string object.In that case there should not be set anything

Comment: can you please post the crashes log ?

Comment: uploaded above @mshariq

Comment: @Syed Hunain seems like a issue with you activity is that you are extending a ListActivity for Sites. Use extend AppCompatActivity else check your sites.xml and add <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/> in your xml file

Answer (score -2):

You can use shared preference instead of passing through Intent

Saving data into sharedprefrence :

```
public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,   MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "Samsad");
 editor.putInt("idName", 12);
 editor.commit();
```

Retrieve data from preference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
  int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value.
}
```

Set value in text view

```
 TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logged_name);
 txt.setText(name );`
```

Comment: why there should be any need of shared preference just for passing value from on activity to another activity. Shared preference is for data persistance

Comment: Suppose, You have to display logged In user name in multiple Activity, How many place u passed data through Intent. Is it not hectic @AbdulWaheed ?

Comment: we can keep that static in that case.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed , Storing variable as static isn't a good way to store dynamic variable.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed : did u devote my Answer?   Please don't do bro. If you don't like my answer, plz leave as it.

Comment: as far as matter of devoting is concerned I did not do that bro.

Comment: yes you are right keeping values in static variables not a good thing but usage of shared preference is not good without any reason because it takes space